Apple Watch can't always reconnect
Using Xcode to build and deploy the app to my watch, this is what I get:
“Waiting to reconnect to Apple Watch. Previous preparation error: Transport error." And then “Connecting to Apple Watch. Xcode will continue when the operation completes.”
And these messages continue to switch between each other.
Sometimes the watch to connect and the application starts, but more often a scenario occurs with endless reconnection.
I'm using: MacOS 14.4.1 (MacBook Pro 2019; 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5), Xcode 15.3, Watch OS 10.2 (Apple Watch SE 1), iOS 17.1.1 (iPhone 15 Pro).
Any help?
Methods I tried:
Connecting Macbook, iPhone and Watch to the same WIfi network;
Disabling Watch (and  IPhone) from the "Devices and Simulators" menu and setting up Watch (and  IPhone) from the beginning.

For me, this always works in the case of Transport Error:

Quit Xcode
Reconnect to the wifi
Start Xcode, run your app on the watch target, and it should run normally.


This worked for me but only after I turned wifi off and then on again on my computer, watch AND usb-connected iPhone

It worked. Don't doubt.

unbelievable, but it worked on the first try (with iPhone connected by cable)

For me, it even works without quitting Xcode. Just turn off wifi and turn it on again, the Transport error will automatically dissappear and you can continue with debugging.

What has helped me recently much more is to setup a personal hotspot on the iPhone, connect it via usb to the mac and then connect the watch to the hotspot wifi.
